# Append Form And Input To Form jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, mobile, append

I am appending checkboxes to a form based on data returned from an ajax call using jquery mobile. When I append the form and its elements, the form loses all of its styling. The checkboxes should be attached together and the submit button is also in a different style.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bDyZz/)

JS Code:

```
$('#editattendancecontent').append('<p>Who Attended?</p><form id="editattendanceform"><div data-role="fieldcontain"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="editattendancelist"></fieldset></div><input type="submit" value="Save Attendance" data-inline="true" /></form>');
for (var i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    $('#editattendancelist').append('<input type="checkbox" id=\"' + i + '\" class="custom" /><label for=\"' + i + '\">'+i+'</label>').trigger('create');
}
$('input: checkbox').checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Comment: ? I can see no initial styling

Comment: run the code in the fiddle again

Answer (score 0):

Try using document ready and change selector at last line to ":checkbox"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#editattendancecontent').append('<p>Who Attended?</p><form id="editattendanceform"><div data-role="fieldcontain"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="editattendancelist"></fieldset></div><input type="submit" value="Save Attendance" data-inline="true" /></form>');
for (var i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    $('#editattendancelist').append('<input type="checkbox" id=\"' + i + '\" class="custom" /><label for=\"' + i + '\">'+i+'</label>').trigger('create');
}
$(':checkbox').checkboxradio("refresh")

});
```